# Can someone verify whether the following FIRST and FOLLOW sets are correct?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

I am doing an exercise to create FIRST and FOLLOW sets for a grammar. I think what I did is correct but the answer is slightly different from mine. So need help from someone to verify this. Thank you.
The grammar is :

```
    P -> L
    L -> I X
    X -> ; L | EPSILON
    I -> A | C | W
    A -> id := E
    C -> if E then L O endif
    O -> else L | EPSILON
    W -> while E do L end
    E -> E2 R
    R -> Op1 E2 R | EPSILON
    E2 -> T S
    S -> Op2 E2 | EPSILON
    T -> c | id
    Op1 -> < | = | !=
    Op2 -> + | -
```

EPSILON is the real 'epsilon'
And here is my answer the FIRST set for X:

```
    FIRST(; L) = {;}
    FOLLOW(X) = {$, else, end, endif}
```

But the answer given is:

```
    FIRST(; L) = {;}
    FOLLOW(X) = {$, else, end, endif, then}
```

Can someone please verify which one is the correct answer?Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how `then` could be in `FOLLOW(X)`. I get the same answer as you do.

The only thing that can precede `then` in that grammar is an `E` and `E` cannot end with `L`. Furthermore, `FOLLOW(E)` includes `do` as well as `then`, so if a followset includes `FOLLOW(E)`  it would have to include both of those tokens.